# Arduino sscanf parses CSV correctly the first time but returns garbage data or crashes the board subsequently

Tags: csv, parsing, arduino, scanf, serial-communication

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57937668/4999991), I have figured out a small and concise way to pars serial input CSV formatted data using `sscanf`:

```cpp
volatile byte state = LOW;
volatile byte state_ = state;

long val1 = 100; 
long val1_ = val1; // buffer

long val2 = 500; 
long val2_ = val2; // buffer

String inpuSerialBufferString = "";

volatile byte control = LOW; 
volatile byte control_ = control;

void reportSerial() {
  Serial.println(String(millis()) + ", " + String(control) + ", " + 
        String(state) + ", " + String(val1) + ", " + String(val2));
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    inpuSerialBufferString = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    sscanf(inpuSerialBufferString.c_str(), "%d,%d,%d,%d", &control, &state, &val1, &val2);
  }

  if (val1 != val1_ || val2 != val2_ || state != state_ || control != control_) {
    reportSerial();

    val1_ = val1;
    val2_ = val2;
    state_ = state;
    control_ = control;
  }
}
```

for example in I put the below values in the Arduino IDE's serial monitor send :

> 1,0,300,200
>
> 0,1,400,100
>
> 0,1,600,200

I get

> 11628, 1, 0, 300, 200
>
> 22260, 0, 1, 741343632, 741408868
>
> 41760, 0, 1, 741343832, 741408968

or sometimes it doesn't return anything. I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can fix it. Priorities in the code should be

1. safety: the system should have predictable behavior
2. Performance is appreciated
3. The code is better to be concise and readable

**P.S.** I did not post in Arduino StackExchange because I could not find any of the tags `csv`, `scanf` nor `parsing` over there.

Comment: you could check the return value of sscanf (number of received parameters) or debug-print the readString result. (And you could use simpler data types than String objects)

Comment: @datafiddler would you be kind to elaborate, please?

Comment: In Arduino, debugging is done via Serial.print :)

Comment: @datafiddler aha :) ok then. Putting `Serial.println("read: " + inpuSerialBufferString);` after the `readStringUntil` shows that the reading part is ok. and the problem is within `sscanf`

Comment: ... or within `reportSerial()`  ...

Comment: @datafiddler it is less probable, I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199506/discussion-between-datafiddler-and-foad).

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved the problem. From [this post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/1033/35432) using `strtok` to tokenize the C-string and `atoi` for C-string to integer conversion I get so far reliable results. Changing the line:

```
    sscanf(inpuSerialBufferString.c_str(), "%d,%d,%d,%d", &control, &state, &val1, &val2);
```

to

```
    char* pch;
    char* inpuSerialBufferCstring = inpuSerialBufferString.c_str();
    pch = strtok(inpuSerialBufferCstring, ",");
    control = atoi(pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, ",");
    state = atoi(pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, ",");
    val1 = atoi(pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, ",");
    val2 = atoi(pch);
```

There is one small issue that I get the below warning:

> In function 'void loop()':
>
> warning: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
>
> char* inpuSerialBufferCstring = inpuSerialBufferString.c_str();

**P.S.** Thanks to @datafiddler replacing

```
char* inpuSerialBufferCstring = inpuSerialBufferString.c_str();
pch = strtok(inpuSerialBufferCstring, ",");
```

with

```
char inputBuffer[50] ; 
Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', inputBuffer, 50);
pch = strtok(inputBuffer, ",");
```

**P.S.2.** the last digit in the CSV should be `4` digits, not less, not more. so if you want to put `50`, you need to send `0050`. I don't know why is that!

Comment: `char buffer[50] ; Serial.readBytesUtil('\n', buffer, 50);` will avoid manipulating the String.c_str() const char*

Comment: @datafiddler why 50?

Comment: 50 is the maximum line length to read. You're right, for `1,0,300,200` 20 is sufficient. But if you really need `long val1, val2;` a bit more might be better.

Comment: @datafiddler thanks a lot. I think this is so far acceptable. but let's wait if Others can come up with more canonical solutions.

Answer (score 1):

sscanf relies on the format string to specify the size of the destination variable.

In particular, state and control are bytes.  You need to use the "hh" modifier (C99) to read into a char-length variable with %hhd.  Or, you need to use temporary int variables for reading with %d and then do a converting assignment into the byte variables.

You are also using %d for val1 and val2, but those are long int so the formats string needs the "l" modifier -- %ld.

When sscanf is writing an int value into a char variable, it will write int-wide value (either 16-bits or possibly 32-bits depending on the platform), with unpredictable results.

If the variables were in the stack, you would corrupt the stack which would very likely lead to crashes.